# How to cast an MDX measure field?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I am very new to ssas and mdx.

I am trying to compare the results I am getting from SSAS with the SQL database.
Somehow for this particular query it does not match. The data is exactly the same.

I could not see any casting function for MDX.

Any idea what is happening?

SQL:

```
SELECT sum(CAST(LOS_MINUTES as BIGINT))
  FROM [db].[dbo].[ FACT_WARD_STAY]

Result is: 3311473500
```

MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Stay Minutes] } ON COLUMNS FROM [Ward Stays]

Result is: -983493796
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your measure in the cube is an integer it looks like. So you are experiencing an overflow. The negative number is a telltale sign of that.

The easiest way to fix this is to install the free BI Developer Extensions and run [Measure Group Health Check](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/MeasureGroupHealthCheck/).

Comment: Yes, the problem was the type. It was set to int.